# Python: List value effected by following calculation on another variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
import csv


file = open('/Users/username/Desktop/IA_Test.csv', 'r')
text = csv.reader(file)
lists = []
for row in text:
new_row = []
for num_string in row:
    new_num = float(num_string)
    new_row.append(new_num)
lists.append(new_row)
mx = [lists[0], lists[-1]]
x = 0
while x <=1:
    temp_list = mx[x]
    if x == 0:
        temp_list[0] += 0.05
        temp_list[1] -= 0.01
    if x == 1:
        temp_list[0] -= 0.05
        temp_list[1] += 0.01
    mx[x] = temp_list
    x += 1
y = 0
mn = [lists[0], lists[-1]]
print(mn)
while y <= 1:
    temp_list = mn[y]
    if y == 0:
        temp_list[0] -= 0.05
        temp_list[1] += 0.01
    if y == 1:
        temp_list[0] += 0.05
        temp_list[1] -= 0.01
    mn[y] = temp_list
    y += 1
max_gradient = (mx[1][1] - mx[0][1])/(mx[1][0]-mx[0][0])
min_gradient = (mn[1][1] - mn[0][1])/(mn[1][0]-mn[0][0])
print(mx)
print(mn)
```

when running it, the lists variable is effected by the calculation of mx and mn for some reason, and both mx and mn returned the same value, without the effect of the calculation. Please help!

Comment: Your indenting is broken...

Comment: You do not change `lists` after you create it, so the expression `[lists[0], lists[-1]]` evaluates to the same two sublists both times you evaluate it.  It is therefore *impossible* for `mx` and `mn` to have different values.  I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but I suspect that your basic misunderstanding is that assigning a list to a variable does not make a copy of that list, it just gives another name for the existing list.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks mate that really helped. What I am trying to do is to find the max and min gradient for some experiment results. I am here trying to apply different operations to the end and starting point of the data so I can get both the max and min gradients. Any idea how to make the lists that fit my requirement? Thanks a lot for your help.